# Extract URL from HTML in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a function that retrieves a specific URL from an email HTML body.

The URL that I'm trying to retrieve with a regular expression has this form

https://dashboard.stripe.com/emails/receipts/invrc_1GYYpBFlgHQ8OfGyspnJivUe/pdf

So it has this pattern fixed https://dashboard.stripe.com/emails/receipts/invrc_ + alphanumeric string of 24 characters + fixed /pdf

I've tried this regular expression but it always print me "null"

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:"Your receipt from ‪Weglot‬"',0,1)[0];
var messages = threads.getMessages();
var body = messages[0].getBody();

      var url = new RegExp(/https:\/\/dashboard.stripe.com\/emails\/receipts\/invrc_/+/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/+/\/pdf/)

      var data = body.match(url)
      Logger.log(data)
  }
```

Has someone got an idea to fix this regular expression ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a constructor to create this regular expression, the constructor's idea is when you want to convert a string into a regular expression, for example:

let regx = "\d{4}"

regx = new RegExp(regx)

But the way you’re doing it you’re passing a regular expression object and not a regular expression string.

try that way:

let url = /https://dashboard.stripe.com/emails/receipts/invrc.+?/pdf/

Answer (score 1):

This also appears to work...

var url = new RegExp(/https://dashboard.stripe.com/emails/receipts/invrc_[a-z,A-Z,0-9]*/pdf/);

or

var url = new RegExp(/https://dashboard.stripe.com/emails/receipts/invrc_[a-z,A-Z,0-9]{24}/pdf/);